# VAL language and velocity control of industrial robot

Tags: controls, robotics

In my bachelor, I programmed CNC machines. Now, working with an Industrial robot arm, I learn that their programming languages are mostly similar. [VAL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_Assembly_Language) is a [typical example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robot_software#Examples_of_programming_languages_for_Industrial_Robots), for instance:

```
PROGRAM PICKPLACE
  1. MOVE P1
  2. MOVE P2
  3. MOVE P3
  4. CLOSEI 0.00
  5. MOVE P4
  6. MOVE P5
  7. OPENI 0.00
  8. MOVE P1
.END
```

Most of the cases, control of a robot arm is similar to this example. Cleary, move end-effector to a point with a given pose.

But... is there any way that I can control the end-effector (EE) speed? An example is "Move EE to P1 with time duration T1", or "Move EE to P1 with velocity V1" (I could have only seen defining for joint rotational velocity)
In other way of speaking, I can command the EE to move from P0 to P1 but cannot control the duration of that traverse which is necessary in cases of EE velocity control

the experienced in robotics programming and VAL please help! I've stuck in this problem for months

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hunting around for a Puma manual, I found the [PUMA Unofficial User’s Guide](http://rutherford-robotics.com/PUMA/USING%20THE%20PUMA%20ROBOT.pdf) which says:

> **MOVE**
>
> Move the gripper/tool to the location set up. Usually this command follows an APPRO but it is not  required. **The robot will move at the last speed specified**.
>
> Use: MOVE
>
> Example: MOVE PART
>
> In the example the robot would move directly to the location “PART” that was  set up in a previous step.

Emphasis added by me.

Unfortunately setting speed was one of the commands omitted from this guide, which led me to the [User’s Guide to VAL 398H2A](http://rutherford-robotics.com/PUMA/Users%20Guide%20to%20VAL%20398H2A%20%28searchable%29.pdf) which explains (on page 55 in the pdf) that speed depends on the `SPEED` monitor value, the SPEED command (p74) and the which types of motion (see Trajectory control on p39). There are different kinds of MOVE commands, `MOVE`, `MOVES`, `MOVEST` and `MOVET` all have significantly different behaviours.

Given any two of speed, distance and time you can calculate the third, sadly this documentation suggests that speed is in terms of percentage of the 'Normal' speed of the robot and it is not clear how much support there is for the robot assisting in calculating for you any of these three parameters. I cannot imagine that it is not possible however.

Comment: the robot I'm using is a DENSO and there is a command to set speed. But that, in turn, is a rotational speed of a "general" joint which is not rad/s but something else that is not explicit to derive/define as I desire

Comment: thank you for your time on this answer! but does this mean that  there may not be available such a control scheme for industrial robot?

Comment: If you can post a link to the manual for your robot then we can see if we can spot anything you missed. If not, since you still have joint level control you will have to roll your own high level control routines. Look at the [tag:kinematics] and [tag:inverse-kinematics] tags both here and on [Robotics Stack Exchange](http://robotics.stackexchange.com) ([kinematics](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kinematics) and [inverse-kinematics](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inverse-kinematics)).

Comment: this is the programming manual https://www.mediafire.com/?agl76pi7t7v4hjv. The velocity control I'm talking about is not joint velocity but end-effector velocity. But EE_screw = robot_Jacobian*joint_vel which means to control EE velocity, it resolves in control joint velocity. About the inverse kinematic, I've already programmed a module to solve the robot